# In C#, can one modify an application's configuration at runtime, and if so, how?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing an assembly, using C#, which will be accessed via it's COM interface.

For this reason it does not have a specific exe, and therefore no [appname].exe.config.

The assembly requires some application settings.  Is there a way to modify the application settings at runtime, so that it doesn't require [appname].exe.config?

Comment: Are you using System.Configuration already? And the assembly might not be being accessed by the program using COM on that specific executable, but the COM subsystem is certainly going to have to call that executable at some point.

Comment: Billy, I don't understand what you wrote there.  The assembly uses a web service so it requires certain information in the config file.  I'm calling the COM from JavaScript in a browser, so there's no specific executable.  The executable could be any browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way, but it is not all that easy.

The config mechanism in .NET is scoped by AppDomain. If you spawn your own child AppDomain you can specify where its config should be obtained from. All types/objects which you then load and execute in the child AppDomain can pick up their configuration from your specified custom config source.

Tools like NUnit use this technique to allow you to specify the config for the code being tested without having to put it into NUnit.exe.config.

Comment: Thanks.  For now I'll just create an exe and let my COM server launch the exe.